# Want to Add More Sample in Majority Class

Tags: machine-learning

I want to add more sample in majority class (not in minority class using oversampling techniques), how to do this?

let suppose I have a car data set having 100 total samples, with class distribution A= 40 sample, B= 25 sample, C= 20 sample, D= 15 Sample, now my question is I want to add sample in A class, so that A= 200, ............. and left the remaining class unchanged

Answer (score 1):

Any oversampling technique should work just fine.

For example, [SMOTE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf) is a technique for generating samples for a specific class. It works by selecting a class, finding the closest samples and generating one at a random position between them. The algorithm **doesn't** explicitly require those samples be from the minority class. Theoretically, you can apply this principle to the majority class as well.

You can see more details about oversampling techniques (including SMOTE) from [this jupyter notebook](https://github.com/djib2011/python_ml_tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/23_preprocessing_2.ipynb), which implements logic behind manually.

Comment: Dear let suppose I have a car data set having 100 total samples, with class distribution A= 40 sample, B= 25 sample, C= 20 sample, D= 15 Sample, now my question is I want to add sample in A class, so that A= 200, ............. and left the remaining class unchanged

Comment: Yes most oversampling techniques work independently for each class. You can make A=100, or A=200 or A=500 or A=1000, without affecting any other class.

Comment: Dear try to understand, total samples are 100,  in which A=40, B=25, c=20, D=15 , now if I need A= 100, by applying any oversampling technique, then the system generate an error, "ValueError: With under-sampling methods, the number of samples in a class should be less or equal to the original number of samples. Originally, there is 22 samples and 23 samples are asked." And same for oversampling methods

Comment: Try to do it manually like it shows in the notebook

Comment: I read the nodebook in detail, but you did it on artificial data set, while i want to perform it on real dataset

Comment: If you bring your data in the same form (i.e. an encoded numpy array without missing values), it is the same thing.